# Viewing 2D array in WPF Form C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an auto generated 2D array that can have sizes between 2x2 to 7x7, and I would like to show the array on the form. I used double[,] as for my array.
I tried to bind using datagrid (from create data bind Interface) but I couldn't locate my array to bind it with the datagrid.
my 2d array only contains numbers, for example:

```
double[,] myArr = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

I want to show it on the form I'm building in WPF, but I'm new to WPF and to these stuff.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide some code, how did you tried? perhaps some sample of input data & expected output too.

Comment: Updated, I'm kind of new for datagrid and viewing elements on an interface

Comment: use a DataTable and append your array into the table. Then display it in the dataGridView.

Comment: @Astro Agree, but note that DataGridView is a WinForm control.

Comment: @kennyzx Is there DataTabel in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate a `DataTable` from the Array, and use it as the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`.

```
double[,] myArr = {{1,2},{3,4}};

private void PopulateDataGrid()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    for (int j = 0; j < myArr.GetLength(1); j++)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column " + j.ToString()));

    for (int i = 0; i < myArr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < myArr.GetLength(1); j++)
            newRow["Column " + j.ToString()] = myArr[i, j];           
        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```